# Find the limit of a sequence involving products of $\left(1 − \frac{1}{\sqrt{ n+1}}\right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

> Let $ a_n= \left(1 −  \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{ 2}} \right) \dotsm \left(1 −  \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{ n+1}} \right) , n \ge 1~,$ then what is $\lim_{n \to \infty}a_{n}$ ?

My efforts:
\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to \infty} a_{n} &= \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{ 2}} ) \cdot (1 − \frac{1}{\sqrt{ 2}} ) \dotsm (1 −  \frac{1}{\sqrt{ n+1}} ) \cdot (1 +  \frac{1}{\sqrt{ n+1}} )}{(1 +  \frac{1}{\sqrt{ 2}} ) \dotsm (1 +  \frac{1}{\sqrt{ n+1}} )} \\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{ \frac{1}{n+1}}{(1 +  \frac{1}{\sqrt{ 2}} ) \dotsm (1 +  \frac{1}{\sqrt{ n+1}} )} \\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{ \frac{\sqrt{(n+1)!}}{n+1}}{(1 + \sqrt{2}) \dotsm (1+\sqrt{n+1})} \\
&=0
\end{align}

Is this right? If it isn't please provide a correct solution/approach. If this is right please provide an alternative approach(if any)

Comment: Hint: For $0<x<1,$ $\ln(1-x)<-x.$

Comment: It looks like it helps to write this as $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\bigg[\frac{1}{n!}\prod_{k=0}^{n}(k-\sqrt k)\bigg]$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You porbably just made some editing errors vs. your intended solution. Perhaps note that 
$$\begin{align}\left(1+\frac1{\sqrt 2}\right)\left(1+\frac1{\sqrt 3}\right)\cdots\left(1+\frac1{\sqrt {n+1}}\right) &>\left(1+\frac1{2}\right)\left(1+\frac1{3}\right)\cdot \left(1+\frac1{n+1}\right)\\&>1+\frac12+\frac13+\ldots+\frac1{n+1}\end{align}$$

Answer (score 4):

Note that\begin{align}\lim_{n\to\infty}\log\left(\left(1-\frac1{\sqrt2}\right)\times\cdots\times\left(1-\frac1{\sqrt{n+1}}\right)\right)&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\log\left(1-\frac1{\sqrt2}\right)+\cdots+\log\left(1-\frac1{\sqrt{n+1}}\right)\\&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\log\left(1-\frac1{\sqrt{k+1}}\right).\end{align}The sum of this series is $-\infty$, because$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\log\left(1-\frac1{\sqrt{k+1}}\right)=-\sum_{k=1}^\infty-\log\left(1-\frac1{\sqrt{k+1}}\right)\tag1$$and you can apply the comparison test to the right hand side of $(1)$, comparing it with $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{\sqrt{k+1}}$. So, the limit of your sequence is $0$.

Answer (score 2):

That is mostly correct.  I don't know why you introduced the square-root of $(n+1)!$ though.  From the second-last line, the denominator is more than 1 so the whole fraction is less than $1/(n+1)$.  So the limit is squeezed to zero.

Comment: Please see my edits I had made a mistake.... Sorry..